# editing the second item in tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

when creating a list such as "list1" below I wanted to create a mini list and append it into the list to create a tuple. when accessing the tuple I wanted to only change the second item of a tuple (which is a dictionary). Here is a bit of code to represent what I'm confused about

```
list1=[]
tempList=[]
dict_={"a":0, "b":0, "c":0, "d":0}

tempList.append("John")
tempList.append(dict_)

list1.append(tempList)
print(list1)
```

when the list is printed it shows both the name and a dictionary beside it. If I wanted to access the dictionary to edit it, to lets say change the value of a to 1. How would i go around doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
list1[0][1]['a'] = 1
```

Look at your code:

1. you are creating an empty list `list1`, another empty list `tempList` and a dictionary `dict_`.
2. you are appending to `tempList` (length 0) the string `"John"`, therefore `tempList[0] == "John"`.
3. you are appending to `tempList` (length 1) the dict `dict_`, therefore `tempList[1] == dict_`.
4. you are appending to `list1` (length 0) the list `tempList`, therefore `list1[0] == tempList`.

Based on the previous assumptions, we have

```
list[0]    # tempList
list[0][1]    # dict_
list[0][1]['a']    # dict_['a']
list[0][1]['a'] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`list1[0][1]['a'] = desired_value`

`list1[0]` is `tempList` and `list1[0][1]` is `dict_`.

Comment: you are a legend